# How to use utf8 charset in cassandra 2.x using Python

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3

Consider the below MySQL schema,

> CREATE TABLE `table` ( 
>     `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
>     `TEXT` longtext NOT NULL, 
>     PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`), 
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

We would like to store text with special characters in a column of a table, created using Cassandra 2.x.

We know that Cassandra doesn't support directly with a data type, but how we can do that in cassandra itself and not through application layer?

Answer with example is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in type mappings, CQL has identically named `bigint` and `text` types that should work for you:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html

I will also point out that there is no concept of `auto_increment` in Cassandra. For ids you might consider `uuid` or `timeuuid` CQL types.